# Excel Formulas duvida

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou com um duvida e não sei se existe alguma função assim.
Tenho esta tabela

```
 96.549
 160.914
 402.284
 643.654
 1.045.938
 1.609.135
```

e tenho um local onde me irá aparecer um resultado por exemplo:

```
1.200.000,00
```

E eu quero que daquela tabela ele me diga o valor maior a seguir ao 1.200.000,00
Com a função maior não funciona.

Comment: O assunto dessa questão foi escolhido pela comunidade como parte do nosso escopo, e consequentemente não deve ser fechada. Quem quiser dar a opinião pode votar a favor ou contra da seguinte publicação: [Dúvidas sobre como utilizar o Excel ou similar: LibreOffice Calc e OpenOffice Calc](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1436/3117).

Comment: @Math não faz parte do escopo ainda. A votação não é clara. Eu fiz pular para não interferir, uma vez que sou a favor do assunto, mas não está no escopo.

Comment: @JorgeB. não entendi porque não está no nosso escopo, poderia me explicar? Na votação tem 3 vezes mais votos a favor do que contra, para mim isso é um claro sinal de que a maioria está a favor desse assunto.

Comment: @Math não foi adicionado ao post principal. Pelo que eu sei só os que lá estão é que são dentro do escopo.

Comment: Assim como o @Math, eu também acho que essa pergunta está no escopo. Só vi que ela tinha sido encerrada hoje, mas votei para reabrir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se bem entendi você tem uma lista de valores

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

E um valor chave X. Você quer retornar o menor valor que seja maior que X. Correto? Se X for 4, você quer o 5.

Use o seguinte:

```
=MÍNIMO(SE(A1:A10>B1;A1:A10))
```

> Cálcule o mínimo elemento da lista formada pelos elementos que são maiores que B1.

Mas importante: Isso é uma **fórmula matricial**. Ao terminar de digitar aperte <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> em vez de apenas <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

<sub>Fonte: http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excel2010functions/qt/2010-04-26-excel-2010-max-function.htm</sub>

Comment: Mais informações sobre fórmulas matriciais: http://www.ambienteoffice.com.br/excel/formulas_matriciais/